# Match and Replace words between two words

Tags: regex, asp-classic, vbscript

I have this string for example :

```
one two three four START four five four five six END seven
```

I want to search for the word "four" in it to replace it with REPLACED, this will give

```
one two three four START REPLACED five REPLACED five six END seven
```

I know that `START(.*)END` will give the words between and the delimiter.
I tried `START(?<four>)END`, but it gives nothing.

I'm working in Vbscript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`(?<name>` is for named groups.

What you need are look-ahead and look-behind assertions to match the `START.*` and `.*END` pre and post-conditions, without actually matching them.

```
Dim input = "one two three four START four five four five six END seven"
Dim output = Regex.Replace(input, "(?<=START.*)four(?=.*END)", "test")
```

yields: `one two three four START test five test five six END seven`

Comment: Thanks a lot gregmac, it works great in the application Expresso (to test regex), but when I use it in my code, I get a Syntax error in regular expression. If I remove the "<" from the beginning, it removes the error but messes the regex. Do you have any idea why it's giving this error?

Comment: Sorry, apparently vbscript doesn't support lookbehind assertions. There's really no way to do this with a single regex in that case, you'll have to sub-match between START and END, and then do a regular replace in that. Are you stuck with vbscript? FWIW, vbscript is [dead](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vbscript#History) and even [.NET 1.1 supports lookbehind assertions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.71).aspx).

Comment: For this project, I can't switch to c# .Net because the newer version is made with .Net. I have to maintain the older version for the clients that are still using it.
But I saw that I can manage to do it in javascript (I forgot to say that is was web). I just have to find the equivalent.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you want to use regex?

```
Dim oldStr = "one two three four START four five four five six END seven"

Dim newStr = oldStr.Replace("four", "REPLACED")
```

Comment: I don't want all the "four" to be replaced, only those between the two words.

Comment: This replaces also the four before START.